# posix_spawn creates a zombie process and returns success

Tags: c++, linux, posix, child-process, spawn

I'm trying to spawn a child process with `posix_spawn()`. I give the executable name (which exists) but `posix_spawn()` creates a zombie process (I search the process in `ps` and it shows as `<defunct>`). Even when I specify a non-existent executable name, the zombie process is created.

My problem is that I need to know whether the process was spawned successfully or not, but since `posix_spawn` returns 0 (success) and child process' id is valid, I have no way to be notified that an error occurred.

Here's my code (P.S. the executable "dummy" doesn't exist):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <spawn.h>

extern char **environ;

int main()
{
    const char *args[] = { "dummy", nullptr };

    pid_t pid = 0;

    posix_spawn(&pid, "dummy", nullptr, nullptr, const_cast<char **>(args), environ);
    if (pid == 0)
    {
        // doesn't get here
    }
    else
        // this gets executed instead, pid has some value
        std::cout << pid << std::endl;
}
```

With getting status:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <spawn.h>

extern char **environ;

int main()
{
    const char *args[] = { "dummy", nullptr };

    int status = posix_spawn(nullptr, "dummy", nullptr, nullptr, const_cast<char **>(args), environ);
    if (status != 0)
    {
        // doesn't get here
    }
    else
        // this gets executed, status is 0
        std::cout << status << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A child process being a zombie means it finished/died and you need to reap its exit status with `wait/waitpid`.

```
#include <sys/wait.h>
//...
int wstatus; 
waitpid(pid,&wstatus,0);
```

Comment: Probably format that as code so we can see the line breaks.

Comment: @user3132457 I missed the part of the question where you said `dummy` exists. Well then `dummy` has run and finished/crashed and you simply need to reap its status to unzombify it. Zombies are simply finished processes whose exit statuses haven't been reaped by their parent yet.

Comment: `wstatus` is 32512 now. The problem is that I get zombie processes with both existing and non-existing executables...

Comment: `32512` corresponds to the child exiting with `127`. You're supposed to use the `WIF*` macros to interpret the result. If you do `int wstatus=32512; if(WIFEXITED(wstatus)) printf("%d\n", WEXITSTATUS(wstatus));` you'll get 127 printed. 127 is prescribed by POSIX as the exit status if there's a failure in the child and posix_spawn has already returned (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/posix_spawn.html).

Comment: now i do this:
`status = posix_spawn(&pid, "dummy", nullptr, nullptr, const_cast<char **>(args), environ);
if (status == 0)
{
 if (waitpid(pid, &status, 0) != -1)
                printf("child exited");
        else
  perror("waitpid");
`
I get that child exited.